# Регулярное выражение для вложенности 2 уровня

Tags: php

Есть адрес типа `/catalog/cat1/cat2/`, притом, `cat1` и `cat2` могут быть любыми. Нужно регулярное выражение для функции `preg_match`, пропускающее все подобные адреса: начинающиеся с `catalog` и имеющие вложенность до 2 уровня.

```
/\/catalog\/\/\w+\/\w+\//i
```

Это выражение не работает.

Comment: ^\/catalog(\/\w+){1,2}\/$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Нужно регулярное выражение для функции preg_match, пропускающее все подобные адреса: начинающиеся с catalog и имеющие вложенность до 2 уровня*

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
$str = '/catalog/cat1/cat2/';

preg_match('~catalog/(?:[\pL\d-]+/){2}$~', $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Работает правильно, но не пропускает адреса с символом `-`.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все работает.

Comment: Еще вопрос, можно ли сделать так, чтобы адреса `/catalog/cat1/` не пропускались выражением? Только со второй вложенностью.

Comment: Да, не заметил, что там теперь только `{2}` стоит.